# How can I handle a Knockout.js mapper bastard-child?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using the mapper plugin on Knockout.js to handle JSON coming from a server. I've set up a parent and a child, however some children don't have parents. These stray children need a handler to put them in a new parent or model like "foster parent" and have a way to access the foster parent and iterate with a "foreach" in a *separate* list.

Here's a code sample of what I have so far: http://pastie.org/3708368

Where would the handler go for foster parenting? Or can I just prepend the parents with a special foster parent?

The basic use case is the children are unassigned tasks (to give context).

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to draw a lot on this advanced example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UdXr4/

It simulates a seating chart and uses the author's custom plugin, Knockout-sortable. I highly recommend it. After examining the example, I realized there was no need to use a mapper but instead I could define a view that accessed a specific collection.

Props to the author, that's a lot of helpful and useful work.

### Update

There's a much better technique to set properties of children using the `create` during mapping. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/issues/15